# Javascript, how to list different things when clicking different button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript, forgive me asking the simple question.
Is there anyone could guide me how to use javascript to dynamically list different things when clicking different button.

For example: Like this [link](http://francisbond.com/folio/#):

when I click the Brand development, ecommerce development, it will list all related items.

Comment: make a json object for each item when when you select the buttom, use the corresponding value.

Comment: you have to post codes instead of posting some link.

Comment: Assign different ids to them to distinguish each button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create an example on jsFiddle, please check from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3AaC3/)

The HTML content is like:

```
<ul class='product-catlogs'>
<li><a class='product'>All</a>
</li>
<li><a class='books'>Books</a>
</li>
<li><a class='mobiles'>Mobiles</a>
</li>
<li><a class='cars'>Cars</a>
</li>
```

```
<ul class='product-list'>
<li>
    <div class='product books'>book1</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class='product books'>book2</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class='product books'>book3</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class='product mobiles'>Iphone</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class='product mobiles'>Sumsang</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class='product cars'>Mercedes</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class='product cars'>Toyota</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class='product cars'>Ford</div>
</li>
```

The js code is like:

```
$('.product-catlogs a').click(function (e) {
  var tag = this.className;
  $('ul li .' + tag).parent().show();
  $('ul li div').not('.' + tag).parent().hide();
})
```

Comment: Great! you are so helpful! Could you guide me how to make the effect like the site? that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @user3112938 sorry, I'm really not good at implementing a visual effect, it's too cool for me :), implementing it is a arduous job, if you want to implement it, there are two ways to do it: 1) looking for a existed javascript library/plugin which might help you, there are thousands of effect js plugins. 2) analyze the effect, it's a combination of multiple effets like magnifying/shrinking, fading in/out, then you implent each one and combine them all together. Hope this might help you.

Comment: could you recommend some library that could do this kind of this?

Comment: @user3112938, basically I like the simple effects provided by jquery like [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/),it looks simple, but if you are familiar with CSS, you could implement a really powerful one, but there are also some css animation framework, like [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), [Move.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/).